# vb.net clear combobox items

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have two comboboxes that are related. My problem is my combobox2 items will not reset/clear as i select item from combobox1. Instead it keeps adding/appending the new items in the bottom of combobox2. I tried  `ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing` and   `ComboBox2.Items.Clear()` before adding the new items but it still not clear it.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validated
    ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox2.Items.Remove(ComboBox2.DisplayMember)
    sql = "select brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
    da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "cbBrgy")
    ComboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables("cbBrgy")
    ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't do

```
ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
```

Just clear the items

```
ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
```

Comment: I did that but i got this error `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Change your method to...

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
     ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
     sql = "select brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue
     da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql, con)
     da.Fill(ds, "cbBrgy")
     ComboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables("cbBrgy")
     ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname"
 End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: i got sql error since i think `ComboBox1.SelectedValue` is still not trigger in `selectedIndexChanged` unless i validated it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing` and `ComboBox2.Items.Clear()`

Use, `ds.Tables("cbBrgy").Rows.Clear()`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ds.Tables("cbBrgy").Rows.Clear()
```

Instead of

```
ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
```

But ensure that `ds.Table("cbBrgy")` is not `Null` before using that line

Answer (score 0):

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

that is the best way

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not IsNothing(ds.Tables("cbBrgy")) Then
    ds.Tables("cbBrgy").clear
End If

sql = "select brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue
da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, "cbBrgy")
ComboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables("cbBrgy")
ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname"
```

Dispose the tables first before populating it again and then setting it again as DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

First check if data source has a value.
For example:

```
if isnothing(combobox1.Datasource) then
*write your code to populate here
end if.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write the following codes under the `combo2_selectedIndedChange` event

```vb
If Not IsNothing(ds.Tables("cbBrgy")) Then
                ds.Tables("cbBrgy").clear()
            End If
            ComboBox2.DataSource = Nothing
            ComboBox2.Items.Clear()

            Sql = "select brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue
            da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(Sql, Con)
            da.Fill(ds, "cbBrgy")
            ComboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables("cbBrgy")
            ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname"
```

Answer (score -1):

follow this,

> ComboBox.Text = Nothing

this is enough to clear the values in the Combo Box.